# Does every group have a Hamiltonian walk whose reversal is Hamiltonian?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$ be a sequence of elements in $G$.

Let $p_n$ denote the partial product $g_1g_2 \dots g_n$ with $p_0 = e_G$, the identity element of $G$.

Call a sequence $\{g_i\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$ *Hamiltonian* if $G = \{p_0, p_1, \dots, p_{|G| - 1}\}$ as sets.

I'm interested in when the reversed sequence $\{g_{|G|-i}\}_{i=1}^{|G|-1}$  is also Hamiltonian.

### Example

For example, if $G = S_3$ then the sequence $(123), (12), (23), (12), (132)$ is Hamiltonian with $$
\begin{alignat}{2}
p_0 & = e, &&\\
p_1 &= (123), &&\\
p_2 &= (123)(12) &&= (13),\\
p_3 &= (13)(23)  &&= (132),\\
p_4 &= (132)(12) &&= (23),\ \text{and}\\
p_5 &= (23)(132) &&= (12).
\end{alignat}
$$

However, the reversal of this sequence, $(132), (12), (23), (12), (123)$, is not Hamiltonian: $$
\begin{alignat}{2}
p'_0 &= e,        && \\
p'_1 &= (132),    && \\
p'_2 &= (132)(12) &&= (23),\\
p'_3 &= (23)(23), &&= e,\\
p'_4 &= e(12)     &&= (12),\ \text{and}\\
p'_5 &= (12)(123) &&= (23).
\end{alignat}
$$
Nevertheless, there *exists* a (palindromic) Hamiltonian sequence for $S_3$ whose reversal is also Hamiltonian, namely $(123), (123), (12), (123), (123)$: $$
\begin{alignat}{2}
p''_0 & = e, &&\\
p''_1 &= (123), &&\\
p''_2 &= (123)(123) &&= (132),\\
p''_3 &= (132)(12)  &&= (23),\\
p''_4 &= (23)(123) &&= (13),\ \text{and}\\
p''_5 &= (13)(132) &&= (12).
\end{alignat}
$$

## Questions

- Does every finite group have a Hamiltonian sequence whose reversal is also Hamiltonian?
- Does every finite group have a palindromic Hamiltonian sequence?
- Does every (sufficiently large) finite group have a non-palindromic Hamiltonian sequence whose reversal is also Hamiltonian?

Comment: I've confirmed that all dihedral groups and the quaternion group have palindromic Hamiltonian sequences.